# Angular Material: transition custom sidenav from long-form to icons without specifying widths

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, transition

I have a `<sidenav>` that toggles between text-plus-icons and just icons effectively using a menu button, with `<sidenav-content>` auto-resizing with a transition.

The `<sidenav>` itself does not transition. I have its width adjusting based on its contents at the moment, and prefer not to specify widths for each state, but when I try to call an Angular transition without specifying styling of the open and closed states, the transition does not seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<!--HEADER WITH MENU TOGGLE BUTTON-->
<mat-toolbar role="banner" class="flexSpaceBetween">
  <span *ngIf="screenWidth >= 840">
    <button mat-raised-button
            class="menuBtn"
            matTooltip="Minimize menu"
            [matTooltipDisabled]="!isExpanded"
            matTooltipShowDelay="400"
            (click)="toggle()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      Menu
    </button>
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>

<!--SIDENAV-->
<mat-sidenav-container class="fullPage" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav
               mode="side"
               class="mat-elevation-z3"
               [@openClose]="isExpanded ? 'open' : 'closed'"
               [opened]="screenWidth >= 840">
    <div mat-subheader *ngIf="isExpanded">General</div>
    <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let app of generalApps">
      <mat-list-item class="sidebarItem"
                     [matTooltip]="app.tooltip"
                     [matTooltipShowDelay]="tooltipDelay"
                     [routerLink]="app.route">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{app.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">{{app.title}}</span>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="component">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      state('open', style({
        // IF I SPECIFY A WIDTH HERE, TRANSITION WORKS
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        // IF I SPECIFY A WIDTH HERE, TRANSITION WORKS
      })),
      transition('open <=> closed', [
        animate('1s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  isExpanded = true
  toggle() { this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded }
}
```

**EDIT**

Not sure if a jsFiddle will work here with Angular, but created here:

https://jsfiddle.net/3cuhk910/10/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `width:*` in the state 'open', see the example in [docs](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#boolean-values-in-transitions)

```
animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      state('open', style({
        width:'*'
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        width:'0'
      })),
      transition('open <=> closed', [
        animate('1s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

Comment: This seems only to be working in one direction, and throws off the autosize on the sidenav-container... let me try to create a demo.

Comment: @OJT, I made a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ndh3sn) -but not with a sidenav-container :(